# Creating a generic class method update on Cassandra db

Tags: linq, generics, c#-4.0, cassandra-2.0

Examining the documentation at datastax on the cassandra c# driver ([cassandra C# driver documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.5/csharp-driver/reference/linqComponent.html)), the following code is presented:

```
// Update 
users.Where(u => u.UserId == "john")
     .Select(u => new User { LastAccess = TimeUuid.NewId()})
     .Update()
     .Execute();
```

I decided to create a repository like this:

```
    public bool Update(Func<T,bool> whereExpression,Func<T,T> selectExpression)
    {
        try
        {
            this.AllRecords
                .Where(whereExpression)
                .Select(selectExpression)
                .Update()
                .Execute();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

I received the following error:

> Error 1   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Update' and no extension method 'Update' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have imported all the necssary namespaces

> using System.Linq;
>   using Cassandra.Data.Linq;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the construction of your method parameters. If you inspect the Cassandra.Data.Linq namespace, the Where extension method is presented as:

```
public static CqlQuery<TSource> Where<TSource>(this CqlQuery<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate);
```

Hence, you should update your code as:

```
 public bool Update(Expression<Func<T,bool>> whereExpression, Expression<Func<T,T>> selectExpression)
{
    try
    {
        this.AllRecords
            .Where(whereExpression)
            .Select(selectExpression)
            .Update()
            .Execute();

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Also, don't forget to import the following namespace for this to work:

```
using System.Linq;    
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Cassandra.Data.Linq;
```

That's all that you need to do to get this working...